# Automatic generation of heuristic functions for A*?

Tags: artificial-intelligence, graph-algorithm, a-star

Has anyone created a successful algorithm for determining good heuristic functions based on training data? Is it even possible?

Comment: Last when I studied AI as a course, I was told by my faculty that designing a good heuristic function is a tedious job and requires special training as a `heuristician` as a sub branch of maths. I don't believe that a good heuristic function could be made using existing algorithms. Also, try asking this question on [Mathematics Stackexchange](http://math.stackexchange.com/) with some research at hand, don't make it into a opinion poll.

Comment: This site isn't for asking about possibilities, you should attempt to research and develop something and ask questions related to writing code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're talking about training data, I assume you're thinking of, for instance, Machine Learning algorithms?

If you want the A* algorithm to be guaranteed to give you an optimal solution if one exists, you must use an *admissible* heuristic function. This is a function that *never* overestimates the distance between two nodes.

I'll assume the training data you're thinking of looks like a big table, where each row has a pair of nodes, and each row is labelled with the true distance. Then I assume you're thinking of training a Machine Learning algorithm to estimate the distance between pairs of nodes, and use that estimate of the distance as the heuristic. This is definitely possible, and I think may give decent results even in some cases, but I don't think it's likely that you're going to be able to guarantee that such a heuristic is still admissible. So, using a technique like this would likely result in losing the theoretical guarantee of finding optimal solutions. It may still be useful in practice though, for finding (not necessarily optimal) solutions.